# TRUNCATE on a parent table causes deletion of a child table records with NULL value for foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, truncate

Why are all rows deleted in a child table when using TRUNCATE with CASCADE clause on a parent table, even when some records in a child table have NULL value for the foreign key.

As far as I understand, setting a NULL value for a foreign key should not link the data in the given row to a parent table.

The statements that this was tested with, in Oracle 12c and 18 (Live SQL), are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE ports 
  ( 
     port_id   NUMBER, 
     port_name VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT port_description_nn NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     country   VARCHAR2(40), 
     capacity  NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT port_pk PRIMARY KEY (port_id) 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE ships 
  ( 
     ship_id      NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, 
     ship_name    VARCHAR2(20), 
     home_port_id NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT ships_ports_fk FOREIGN KEY (home_port_id) REFERENCES ports ( 
     port_id) ON DELETE CASCADE 
  ); 

INSERT INTO ports 
VALUES      (315, 
             'ATLANTA', 
             'USA', 
             100000); 

INSERT INTO ships 
VALUES      (4000, 
             'CODD LAND ROVER', 
             315); 

INSERT INTO ships 
VALUES      (4001, 
             'CODD VESSEL TWO', 
             NULL);
```

After this, the following statement

```
TRUNCATE TABLE PORTS CASCADE;
```

deletes all rows in SHIPS table, even though the 'Codd Vessel Two' has NULL value for the HOME_PORT_ID, which is a foreign key.

Is this an expected result, due to the ON DELETE CASCADE clause when the foreign key was created?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: `TRUNCATE` is not the same as `DELETE`...

Comment: I think Mat is trying to point you [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/truncate-table-cascade-12cr1). With the specific quote on `truncate cascade`: "Notice all rows have been removed from the dependent tables, even those that were not related to rows in their parent table. It's worth noting this difference between the DELETE CASCADE and the TRUNCATE CASCADE commands."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this an expected result?

Yes. The documentation of [TRUNCATE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10007.htm#SQLRF01707)  command says that:

> **CASCADE**
>
> If you specify CASCADE, then Oracle Database **truncates all child
>   tables** that reference table with an enabled ON DELETE CASCADE
>   referential constraint. This is a recursive operation that will
>   truncate all child tables, granchild tables, and so on, using the
>   specified options.